# How do I enable click on listview?

Tags: android, listview

I'm currently working on a code which is written by someone else in my office. I need to enable selection of items in the listview. I know I have to use setOnClickListener. Can someone guide me through this? I've written:

Edit:

```
listview.setOnClickListener( (View.OnClickListener) this );
```

Now what do I do?

I need to select an int value and pass it on to another function, which is used to retrieve a certain set of values from a db.

Comment: in `ListView`/`RecyclerView` you have to use `setOnItemClickListener()`

Comment: Make sure your base class where you`'ve declared the ```listview``` implements ```OnItemClickListener```, if you'd like to set it with ```this``` and casting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
listviewName.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            //variable position will give you the required element/object from the array list.

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    YourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new ListView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long l) {
        try {
           Toast.makeText(this,"Position is===>>"+pos , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Nay, cannot get the selected index");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
     ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.quoteX2);
     list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            // -  -- -  -Your Code here
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps!